# show value in alert message by script in Kendo-Template

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui

I'm using Kendo UI grid. I want it has delete, update button in every rows. About update button, I want to use script to call small window page. But now I want to send value of data's id that I want it show in `alert()` . but when I click it doesn't work. it doesn't show anything. Only link changed .. How I do that?

```
<script>      
$(document).ready(function () {
        $("#edit").click(function (e) {

            alert("show ID of clicked rows");
        });
});</script>
<script id="rowTemplate" type="text/x-kendo-tmpl">
    <tr>
        <td id="id"  width= "34px">
            #= aid #
        </td>
        <td  width= "84px">
            #= aname #
        </td>
        <td width= "84px">
            <a id="edit" href="//#">@Resources.edit</a>  |
            <a href="Delete/#=aid#">@(Resources.delete)</a>
        </td>
    </tr> </script>
```

Comment: If your using a kendo template script, why are creating an HTML table? Check out the documentation. They've got everything you need there http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui

Answer (score 0):

How many times do you use this "rowTemplate"? I guess more than one, correct? How do you set and `id` that is a constant in the second `td`? HTML `id` must be unique.

Try changing it into a CSS class:

```
<script>      
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".edit").click(function (e) {
        alert("show ID of clicked rows");
    });
});
</script>

<script id="rowTemplate" type="text/x-kendo-tmpl">
    <tr>
        <td width="34px">
            #= aid #
        </td>
        <td width= "84px">
            #= aname #
        </td>
        <td width= "84px">
            <a class="edit" href="//#">@Resources.edit</a>  |
            <a href="Delete/#=aid#">@(Resources.delete)</a>
        </td>
    </tr>
</script>
```

Comment: I want to send data's id... "aid"